# The key didn't match any rows in the table

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

I'm attempting to refresh my Azure Analysis Services Model using the PowerShell command below.

```
Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -Server $ServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName –RefreshType Full -Credential $cred
```

### Problem

I get an error message back, however it isn't very helpful. Does anyone know how to find out which part of my model is broken?

> Invoke-ProcessASDatabase : Failed to save modifications to the server.
>   Error returned: 'The key didn't match any rows  in the table.. The
>   exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
>
> Technical Details: RootActivityId:
>   7b0af12c-c9cf-47f9-8abb-9aaff8f0f6f5 Date (UTC): 4/26/2019 3:21:48 PM
>   The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the
>   IDbCommand interface. The command has been canceled.. The exception
>   was raised by the IDbCommand interface. The command has been
>   canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. The
>   command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand
>   interface. The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by
>   the IDbCommand interface. The command has been canceled.. The
>   exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. The command has been
>   canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. The
>   command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand
>   interface. The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by
>   the IDbCommand interface. The command has been canceled.. The
>   exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. The command has been
>   canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. The
>   command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand
>   interface. The current operation was cancelled because another
>   operation in the transaction failed. The command has been canceled..
>   The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. The command has
>   been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDataReader interface.
>   The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the
>   IDataReader interface. '. At line:24 char:1
>   + Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -Server $ServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseN ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (-Redacted-:String) [Invoke-ProcessASDatabase], OperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ProcessASDatabase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by a mismatch in the schema in AAS query and the datasource. Have any of the database tables been edited in any way? If so, that is the most likely culprit.

[Invoke-ProcessTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-processtable?view=sqlserver-ps) and [Invoke-ProcessPartition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-processpartition?view=sqlserver-ps) can be used to process individual parts of the model that you suspect to be an issue.